# Backbone/Marionette collection.create not firing callbacks

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

This might just be me not understanding Marionette's auto rendering, but I've been trying to add a model to my collection using .create and have been running into issues.

Calling .create hits the server, gets a successful response, and automatically hits my itemView.

What I need to do is call .create, get a successful response, and fire the callback in my create call.

My code currently looks like this:

```
collection.create(data, {
    wait: true,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

My success and error callbacks get totally ignored and the itemView is automatically initialized. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to reproduce but for me it works well. I'm using sinon.js fake server for this example. Hope my code could be helpful.

html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="appRegion">nothing yet here</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
// fake API
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith("GET", "/api/models", [200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
JSON.stringify([{
    'name': 'foo'
}, {
    'name': 'bar'
}])]);

server.respondWith("POST", "/api/models", [200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
JSON.stringify({
    'name': 'bazz'
})]);

// application
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.Model,
    url: "/api/models"
});


var MyApp = Marionette.Application.extend({
    regions: {
        appRegion: '#appRegion'
    }
}),
    MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        className : 'myView',
        template: _.template('<b><%=name%></b>')
    }),
    CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView: MyView
    })
    var collection = new Collection();

var myApp = new MyApp({
    container: '#app'
});
var collectionView = new CollectionView({
    collection: collection
});
myApp.appRegion.show(collectionView);

collection.fetch();

server.respond();

collection.create({}, {
    wait: true,
    success: function(model) {
        console.log('success %o', model);
    }
});

setTimeout(function(){
    server.respond();
},2000)
```